# Drools : Template for Multiple patterns of same format

Tags: drools, rule-engine

I have a Drools rule Rule file as:

```
package com.test

import com.test.fact.Feature;

global com.test.Course subjects;

rule "CS"
when
    Feature( subjectName=="Math", rating >= 6)
    Feature( subjectName=="Computers", rating >= 9)
    Feature( subjectName=="Electronics", rating >= 3)
then
    subjects.addSubjectName("Computers");
end

rule "Physics"
when
    Feature( subjectName=="Math", rating >= 9)
    Feature( subjectName=="Physics", rating >= 9)
then
    subjects.addSubjectName("Physics");
end
```

The patterns in the when clause can be changed as the pattern definitions defining a subject is placed in database table as: 
PatternDefinition (PatternName,FeatureName, FeatureValue) where PatternDefinition is the table name with PatternName, FeatureName and FeatureValue are the columns.

E.g. For the rule "CS", the definitions would be with pattern name "CS" as follows:

```
Row 1 -> CS, Math, >=9
Row 2 -> CS, Computers, >=9
Row 3 -> CS, Electronincs, >=3
```

I cannot change the Database tables as there is a huge amount of data and are being referred to lot of sub-projects.

The definitions for a particular rule can change as new subjects are added or if definitions are changed (lets say rating requirement for a particular subject changes). These are changed in the database from background.

I am required to convert the above rule to Drools-template so that application-startup will automatically pick up changes in the database and prepare the Drools rule file reading the template and Database data.

I have been able to configure a single Feature as template but not multiple in a single rule.

Please suggest.

Comment: have a look at this, this might help you.... http://opensourcesoftwareandme.blogspot.in/2015/08/dynamically-create-rules-using-drools.html

Comment: So if I am understanding correct, I need to return a toString() implementation that will eventually replace the single template property as multiple conditions. What I mean is that if I can keep a map of "Physics" against ListOfFeatures, then on getting the list, I will have a toString() implementation that will concatenate the features (with new line) to form the complete FeatureSet for the template.

Comment: yes true, let me know if this helps

Answer (score 0):

A primitive solution would be to define n templates, for 1, 2,... n rows per rule/pattern name.

For a more intelligent solution one would need to know the purpose of these rules. Which Feature Name is to be added to the global list, and why?

Comment: How can we then group those individual templates to form a single rule. Say `Feature( subjectName=="Math", rating >= 9)` is in template1 and `Feature( subjectName=="Physics", rating >= 9)` is in template2. But together they form the **rule "Physics"**. Could you please provide an example.

Comment: These two examples aren't two templates, they are two *instances* of one template, with subject name and rating value being the parameters for the instantiation. - Perhaps you answer my question - as it is I don't see the purpose of these rules.